# Import model in Django's settings.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-settings

I'm trying to define a constant with the value of model's class in the `settings.py` to provide a dynamically-defined FK for one of my models:

```
from catalog.models import Product
PRODUCT_MODEL = Product
```

No surprise it's leading to an `AppRegistryNotReady` exception:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

since there was no call to `django.setup()` method.

If I add

```
import django
django.setup()
```

in front of the model's import, instead of `AppRegistryNotReady` exception, I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'PRODUCT_MODEL'
```

when I'm using

```
from django.conf import settings
...

product = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.PRODUCT_MODEL, 
    related_name='order_items')
```

Is there any way to implement this without errors?

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.9.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't import models or call `django.setup()` in your settings file.

Instead, use a string to refer to your model.

```
PRODUCT_MODEL = 'catalog.Product'
```

Then, in your models, you can use the setting.

```
product = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.PRODUCT_MODEL, 
    related_name='order_items',
)
```

Note that the [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) setting uses a string like this, you do not import the user model in the settings file.

Comment: Yep, the "string-way" is what I initially done and it worked.
I'm just curious if there are any way to benefit from Python's dynamic and import directly class or module...

Answer (score 4):

Store the model name as a string.

In settings.py:

```
PRODUCT_MODEL = 'YourModel'
```

In your models.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
....
field = models.ForeignKey(AppConfig.get_model(PRODUCT_MODEL))
```

(This works from Django 1.9.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `catalog.Product` in settings and lazy import